# QML application does not receive signals from python backend

Tags: python, qt, qml

I have tried a minimal example of using Python as the backend for the QML application. But weirdly, the signals from the backend have not been received in the QML application.

The QML code is as below:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property QtObject backend
    property string text

    Connections{
        target: backend
        function onSig(msg){
            mainWindow.text = msg
            console.log(msg)
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: content
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            id: textField
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "white"
            text: mainWindow.text
        }
    }
}
```

The code for Python backend is:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QObject

class backEnd(QObject):
    sig = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._test()
        return

    def _test(self):
        colors = ["blue", "green", "red", "white", "black"]
        for color in colors:
            self.sig.emit(color)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    backend = backEnd()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)
    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(str(qml_file))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have read several tutorials on how to connect the Python backend to the QML application and all of them do it like how I did it here. So, this behavior is weird for me and I don't know what should I do.

Comment: You're emitting the signal during the instance creation, at that point the backend is not set yet, so it will not be received. If you just want to test it, delay the function call by using a `QTimer.singleShot(0, self._test)`, otherwise call it *externally* once the whole backend is finalized.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your answer. I don't know exactly what you mean by "call it externally". Do you mean emitting the signal inside a slot of the back end class which is called by some thing else?

Comment: What I meant is to call the method from outside of the instance instead of within: `backend._test()` right after `engine.load()` (or after `if not`, it wouldn't change that much). The point remains, the signal is emitted while the object is created, and before any connection to that signal even exists, which, in your case, is only done when the QML engine loads its contents: at that point, the signal has already been emitted, and you'll never receive it unless it's emitted *again* (which is what `QTimer.singleShot()` would eventually do, since it's triggered when the event loop finally starts.

Comment: @musicamante, you are right. I moved the call to `backend._test()` into the line before `sys.exit(...)` and now it works. thanks a lot for your answer!